# Sphere 360-texture low quality

Tags: unity-game-engine, texture-mapping, google-cardboard

I'm creating an app to show 360 images with Cardboard.
I created a scene in Unity using Cardboard camera and sphere. I mapped 360-image to a sphere texture. 
When viewing the texture is low quality and has sawtooths so the details are not good quality.

Any ideas to solve this texture problem? I tried a script which creates a different kind of sphere but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an [icoshpere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedron) for this to work, you'll still gonna get some distortion near the polls, but it's far better than the uv ones that Unity provides.

The second thing is that you'll need a high detail icoshpere for this to work, as you'll need more vertexes.

The third thing is the textures quality and size. I think the default fov for Unity is around 60, but you'll map the texture for a fov of 360, so you'll need textures of higher size compared to the on screen texture you are using.

You can look over this [article](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/creating-an-octahedron-sphere/162) if you want more details about the differences between icoshperes and uv spheres, or just go to the bottom of the article and download the unity project. The project includes already made icoshperes and you can experiment with them to find out which one is best suited for your project. I'm using the **Octahedron Sphere 4 R1**. Any less polys and there are too many distortion, any higher one and the fps drops to much.